# Fix JDBC in dynamic web project

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to check the data in the database through servlet but the html page doesnt read the servlet page ..

The error :

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My Login page :

```
<form action="validate" method="Post">
    User name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    User password:
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="psw">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My serlvlet code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.SetContenttype("text/html");
    String uname = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("psw");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "root", "1234");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = Con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1, uname);
    pstmt.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("record found");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Stu.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        System.out.println("record not found");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    Con.close();

    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login page you should specify

```
    <form action="/LoginServlet" method="post">
```

Also check if you have specified servlet mapping in web.xml or annotate your servlet class with 
      @WebServlet("/LoginServlet")

```
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>/LoginServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

this problems rises when the action cant find the servlet specified, and its could be for many resonse.

- Please check your @WebServlet anotation, its could be

  @WebServlet(name="validate")

something like that, you have to give it

`@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/validate")`

, or your can use

`@WebServlet("/validate")`

Other issue you can add in your form in action section

```
<form action="${requestScope.getContextPath}/validate" method="Post">
```

Wish i was helpfull.